# GitLab pipeline set to public but behaves private

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

I'm using GitLab for open-source projects, they are all configured with the same visibility settings.

However, one of the projects is behaving differently from the rest.

- The **Project visibility** is **Public**.
- I've configured **Pipelines** visibility with **Public** and **Everyone With Access**.

[image]

While the repository is accessible, users aren't able to download artifacts from the project's pipelines.

It works when I'm authenticated to my account, but fails in a private browser or in the terminal via curl/wget.

Is there a setting I'm missing that impacts pipeline/artifact visibility?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pipeline visibility depends on multiple settings in different locations.

It has to be set as **Public** in `Settings > CI/CD > General pipelines` *as well*, otherwise it will not be publicly accessible at all.

> #### Visibility of pipelines
>
> Pipeline visibility is determined by:
>
> - Your current [user access level](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html).
> - The **Public pipelines** project setting under your project’s **Settings > CI/CD > General pipelines**.
>
> — https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#visibility-of-pipelines